# How to modularize a (NotificationManager) library for Android?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a customized `MyNotificationManager` im my app (`package com.ralfi.myapp.mynotifier;`), which works so far. I would like to extract this `mynotifier` package as a single *.aar library, which in turn I can import to all my other apps and use it there.

```
package com.ralfi.mynotifiier;
class MyNotificationManager {
 Context context;
 NotificationManager notificationManager;

 public class MyNotificationManager(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 }

 //..
public void sendNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this.context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```

I would instantiate it in my android app project and make ist static availabe for any other classes in there.

```
import com.ralfi.mynotifiier.MyNotificationManager; // e.g.: delivered in a *.aar

class MyRootApplication
  //..
  private static MyNotificationManager myNotificationManager;
  //..
  void onCreate(){
    myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(context);
    //..
  }

  public static AppNotificationManager getAppNotificationManager() {
    return appNotificationManager; 
  }
}
```

**Main Question**: As you can see in `MyNotificationManager.sendNotification()` I need the `MainActivity.class` as a parameter for Intent constructor and the X.addParentStack() method. When I intent to deliver the MyNotificationManager as a *.aar library, I would not know then, what this MainActivity would be called in the Android App project? How can I make this generic?

**Side Question**: Is that the proper way to use it any class in the final project by calling `MyRootApplication.getAppNotificationManager().sendNotification(...)`? Are there maybe ay better design patterns? (Dependecy Injection?)

Answer (score 0):

MainQuestion-  you'd pass it in the .class variable at creation time.  Foo.class is actually a variable of type Class.  Although you're assuming that an app has a "main activity" and that's where it wants all notifications to go-  I find that's rarely the case.

Side question-  I don't think I'd assume that all notifications want to go to one activity.  In fact I wouldn't even assume that all notifications don't have extra parameters they need bundled into the intent.  I'd make sendNotification take an intent as a parameter.

Comment: What would make the difference? When I assume a simple case that my app has a MainActivity (the main functionality) and a sencond SettingsActivity (where I can make some configurations). What would make the difference, when I would tap on two Notifications with each of them as a parameter? Wuold they call the app with the corresponding activity set a focused?